# qtcreator does not use specified compiler

Tags: c++, gcc, qt-creator

I want to use gcc6 for my project and use qtcreator as ide.
my project uses cmake.

in 'build&run' -> 'compiler' i added g++-6 as compiler 'gcc6'.
in 'kits' i changed the compiler to 'gcc6'.

when importing the project and hovering over a target, the popup shows compiler as 'gcc6'.

when clicking 'configure' and running cmake i get following output:

```
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
```

and c++ is used when compiling. this is what i get when following the links:

```
/usr/bin/c++ -> /etc/alternatives/c++ -> /usr/bin/g++ -> g++-5
```

so it seems the qtcreator ignores my settings.

it would be enough to set default cmake-parameters for the qtcreator kit, but i found no option.

what can i do to fix this? (or am i doing something wrong?)

Comment: I'd guess the compiler setting in Creator is for qmake only, CMake might have its own idea on how to run the compiler. You probably have to put the compiler settings in the CMakeLists.txt file.

Answer (score 4):

I also ran into this problem. Don't know what you can do to fix the Kit problem, but you can add the following to your *pro* file to point to another gcc and g++ version:

```
QMAKE_CC = gcc-4.8
QMAKE_CXX = g++-4.8
```